# (Python) different behaviors of grpc Servicer class and experimental API class regarding async

Tags: python, asynchronous, server, grpc

After writing a .proto file (i.e. `example.proto`) regarding a service (i.e. `service Example`), following classes can be found in the resulting `example_pb2_grpc.py`.

1. `class ExampleServicer`
2. `class Example` (Annotated as an EXPERIMENTAL API)

However, using 1. `ExampleServicer` for making a server leads to that server performing in a synchronous fashion (job 2 is started after job 1 is finished), using 2. `Example` leads to a asynchronous server (job 2 is started before job 1 is finished).

I was wondering the difference between these two classes and their underlying functionalities.
(These two classes are handled exactly the same when developing servers.)

env. `python 3.8.10`, `grpcio 1.43.0`

Answer (score 0):

I'll reference the [helloworld generated code](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/7223a9e5fe713654ba7b989a140600af22a1669a/examples/python/helloworld/helloworld_pb2_grpc.py) as an example here.

[GreeterServicer](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/7223a9e5fe713654ba7b989a140600af22a1669a/examples/python/helloworld/helloworld_pb2_grpc.py#L29) is indeed an interface for implementing server handlers, as you mention above. However, the [Greeter](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/7223a9e5fe713654ba7b989a140600af22a1669a/examples/python/helloworld/helloworld_pb2_grpc.py#L51) class is for *client* connections, not servers. There may be server functionality added in the future, but currently just client connections. This class is simply for convenience. This API does not require explicit channel creation when calling it, so it simplifies the call. See [this example for how to use it](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/7223a9e5fe713654ba7b989a140600af22a1669a/examples/python/no_codegen/greeter_client.py#L38).